# Keep Me logged in with checkbox Android

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I am creating an android app for which I have created login and home pages. I want to implement the "keep me logged in" functionality in the login page. I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500265/keep-me-logged-in-checkbox-android) but still cannot get the result well. I think i have a problem in ordering the code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    isChecked= settings1.getBoolean("isChecked", false);

    if (isChecked) {
        Intent rememberMe = new Intent(LoginPage.this, HomePageActivity.class);
        startActivity(rememberMe);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
    }


    // Retrieving SharedPreferences
    sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Retrieving editor
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    rememberMeCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                    0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `but still cannot get the result well. I think i have a problem in ordering the code` explain more what behavior you are getting using current code

Comment: i think i should use fragments to get the result !

Comment: no need to go for Fragments. just explain problem probably to get help from us

Comment: After you call `startActivity()`, you probably want to `finish()` the current activity and `return` from onCreate - otherwise the code will just continue without `setContentView()` being called.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user opens the app check if the shared preferences contains your user detail keys. Store keys if user selects the keep me logged in.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    shrd=getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(shrd.contains("username")==true && shrd.contains("password")==true)
    {

        Intent in=new Intent(LoginScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();


    }
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
```